# How to reduce Time till first byte - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http2

I've got a huge TTFB of around 6.5 seconds when the whole load time of my site is around 7 seconds

I've done the basics to try and reduce this - updating to the latest version of PHP, switched to https so I can enabled HTTP/2 where possible and enabling caches where possible such as OpCache which I've checked is up and running correctly with my phpinfo which you can see here

https://www.camp-site-finder.com/phpinfo.php

This and setting up caching plugins such as W3 Total Cache has reduces the issue but on search queries there still seems to a large wait

As you can see here for example if you check the Network tab of developer tools

https://www.camp-site-finder.com/?sfid=48&_sf_s=england

So my question really is how can I debug this, are there tools out there to test what is taking so long or is this a non issue? Is that wait period really acceptable? Any advice or pointing me in the direction of some research I could do I'd be hugely grateful.

Comment: Is it your hosting? Would a faster server, more RAM/CPU cores, using SSDs, etc help?

Comment: @MrGlass It's a fairly decent server I'd say - I have other similar Wordpress sites running on it receiving much quicker results, it's no where near using up its resources and usually well under 50% of what's available ... but yes, that would likely be a solution

Comment: Are there any plugins you can disable that you don't need? Or even temporarily to see where the bottle neck may be? Also, look at your MySQL "slow query" log to see if there's anything you can gleen from that.

Answer (score 2):

If a search is slow, it is almost always a bottleneck of the database.

Which DB-Server do you use? I see MySQL and SQLight extensions active, but I guess it is the former. But do you use MySQL or MariaDB? You could try MariaDB or some other drop-in replacement for MySQL (like Percona) which should increase DB performance.
Also you should log slow queries in the DB server, so you can check which DB queries is that slow. I guess you might have to many joins. In that case you should need to restructure the database.

Additionally you could try do follow some basic db performance tips like these:

- Indexing
- Assigned memory

etc.
Just google for 'increase MySQL perfomance' and you should find plenty of adwise.

Comment: Yes it uses MySQL - great advice, I'll Google as recommended and see how I get on

Comment: This. The site comes down in a lump, which suggests that all the scripts, images, etc are being retrieved and the delay is the data. As the results are pagified I don't think lazy loading would help.

Comment: Server set up also has an impact on TTFB as a shared server will take longer than a dedicated one. I had a similar issue in the past, spent time optimising code and the DB but changing to a better server (AWS) made all the difference.

Comment: As OP can do a lot of things I assumed it was a dedicated server he uses

Comment: It is a dedicated server - I'm going to investigate the DB as it sounds like that's where the issue lays with these comments and I haven't yet tried any optimization on that ...